# Унаследовать переменную от класса-родителя

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Auto {
public:
    double inc;
    double Auto1(double a, double b, string val) {

        inc = b - a;
        cout << "Прибыль: " << inc << val << endl;
        return inc;
    }
};

class BMW : public Auto {
public:
    void BMW1() {
        cout << "Престиж: " << inc <<" престижей"<< endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    double a, b,inc;
    string val;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите затраты на производство одного автомобиля: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите стоимость покупки: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Введите валюту: " << endl;
    cin >> val;
    Auto s1;
    s1.Auto1(a, b, val);
    BMW s2;
    s2.BMW1();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как унаследовать переменную `inc` в классе `BMW`? Объясните, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Переменная уже унаследовалась. Чего Вы ещё от неё хотите?

Comment: она не унаследовалась, классом БМВ выводит заоблачное число, которое точно не должно выводить

Comment: Вообще-то неплохо бы конструкторы определить... И потом, `inc` у вас переменная не статическая, так что, меняя ее в `s1`, в `s2` вы ее никак не получите. Сами классы у вас не несут никакой нагрузки, вы их просто "веревочками привязали", лишь бы было...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытаюсь воспользоваться телепатией, скорее всего автор хотел что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Auto
{
public:
    double inc;
    double Auto1(double a, double b, string val) {
        inc = b - a;
        cout << "Прибыль: " << inc << val << endl;
        return inc;
    }
};

class BMW : public Auto {
public:
    void BMW1() {
        cout << "Престиж: " << inc <<" престижей"<< endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    double a, b,inc;
    string val;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите затраты на производство одного автомобиля: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите стоимость покупки: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Введите валюту: " << endl;
    cin >> val;
    BMW s2;
    s2.Auto1(a, b, val);
    s2.BMW1();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: понял свою ошибку, спасбо!и